# Is there a way to guarantee an interface extends a class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Suppose I have the following situation:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
  public void turnOn() { ... }
}

public interface Flier {
  public void fly();
}
```

Is there a way that I can guarantee that any class that implements `Flier` must also extend `Vehicle`? I don't want to make `Flier` an abstract class because I want to be able to mix a few other interfaces in a similar manner.

For instance:

```
// I also want to guarantee any class that implements Car must also implement Vehicle
public interface Car {
  public void honk();
}

// I want the compiler to either give me an error saying
// MySpecialMachine must extend Vehicle, or implicitly make
// it a subclass of Vehicle. Either way, I want it to be
// impossible to implement Car or Flier without also being
// a subclass of Vehicle.
public class MySpecialMachine implements Car, Flier {
  public void honk() { ... }
  public void fly() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Interfaces extend Interfaces. (Abstract) Classes (partially) implement Interfaces and extend other classes.

Comment: Try my suggestion, you cant compile MySpecialMachine without extends from Vehicle!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Java interfaces cannot extend classes, which makes sense since classes contain implementation details that cannot be specified within an interface..

The proper way to deal with this problem is to separate interface from implementation completely by turning `Vehicle` into an interface as well. The `Car` e.t.c. can extend the `Vehicle` interface to force the programmer to implement the corresponding methods. If you want to share code among all `Vehicle` instances, then you can use a (possibly abstract) class as a parent for any classes that need to implement that interface.

Comment: if he cant implement the correspondimg methods? if only Vehicle can implement the corresponding methods? think about.

Comment: @PeterRader: I do not understand what you are taking about. He has *already* implemented the methods in `Vehicle`. All he'd have to do is turn `Vehicle` into an interface and move any implementation details to an abstract base class if necessary...

Comment: @PeterRader: So? Either `Vehicle` will be turned into and interface and its code moved into an another base class, or `Vehicle` will have to implement a new interface, lets say `VehicleInterface',`which will then be extended by all other interfaces. The end result is technically the same...

Comment: OP not asked about the proper way. Op asked how to implement a duress to extends from Vehicle too if the class is flyable. Your way automatically make the converse that all Vehicles must be instances of Flier too. Well i take my car right now and fly home ;D

Comment: @PeterRader: *what* on earth are you talking about? How does `interface Car extends Vehicle` make all `Vehicle` instances extend `Car` as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22124/discussion-between-peter-rader-and-thkala)

Comment: that's NOT always possible. For example if I'm using a framework of third party library exposing Vehicle and I need to create the Car interface and I want to make sure it always extend Vehicle I can't just rewrite Vehicle. Concrete example: `RecyclerView.Adapter` class from Android. I want to define an interface for manipulating the RecyclerView but I also want the implementor of that interface to always extend `RecyclerView.Adapter`. I don't think Java let you do that but it sucks.

Answer (score 9):

You could rearrange your classes and interfaces like this:

```
public interface IVehicle {
  public void turnOn();
}

public abstract class Vehicle implements IVehicle {
  public void turnOn() { ... }
}

public interface Flier extends IVehicle {
  public void fly();
}
```

This way all implementations of `Flier` are guaranteed to implement the *protocol* of a vehicle, namely `IVehicle`.

Comment: One little nitpick - if the `I*` convention is to be used (which, btw, never seemed all that Java-y to me) then it should be used for *all* interfaces...

Comment: @thkala: Yes, the `I*` convention is mainly a .NET thing. I used it because I was in need of the different but related name to `Vehicle`. Cleaning up the names to have a consistent naming certainly will help.

Answer (score 4):

If you have control on the `Vehicle` classes just extract `Vehicle` as an interface and then provide a base implementation.

If you have no control over `Vehicle` class, for example because it is part of a framework you are using or a third party library, it's not possible to do in Java.

The closest thing you can do is using Generics multiple wildcards notation.

```
<T extends Vehicle & Car>
```

But you can't really apply it directly to Car unless you do something like this:

```
public interface Car<T extends Vehicle & Car>() {
    T self();
}
```

Which is bot weird and do not enforce the self method to actually return self, it's just a strong hint/suggestion.

You would implement a `Car` like this:

```
public class CitroenC3 extends Vehicle implements Car<CitroenC3> {
    @Override
    public CitroenC3 self() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

one can use a `Car<?>` like this:

```
Car<?> car = obtainCarInSomeWay();
Vehicle v = car.self();
Car c = car.self();
```

they should be both valid syntax.

What the compiler enforce here is that what you specify in `Car<WHICH>` as WHICH must both extend `Vehicle` and implement `Car`. And by adding `self()` you are saying to the programmer that the `T` object is supposed to be the object itself, thus forcing the wildcard instance to match the class if he want to be compliant with the specification.

in Java 8 you can even define a default implementation for the self method.

I also wish there was a better way to handle something like this.

Answer (score 2):

It's a strange requirement, but you can accomplish something of the sort with Generics:

```
<T extends MyInterface & MyAbstractClass>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question shows that you haven't grasped the essence of `interface` and `class`. Forgetting the concrete Java syntax right now, all you need to understand first is that: interface is a set of protocol, which should be implementation-agnostic. It makes no sense to let an interface extend a class(which is implementation-oriented).

Back to your concrete question, if you want to guarantee that a `Flier` is always a kind of  `Vehicle`, just change the latter to an `interface` and let former extends it(It does make sense to extend one protocol from the other protocol). After that, you may create any class(abstract or concrete) that implements `Vehicle` or `Flier`.

Comment: This may be the case, but the Op might be using an external framework in which `Vehicle` is a class (even though it should be an interface).

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a new Package
2. Create a new interface (ie. HiddenOne) with scope "default" with a method "implementMe(HiddenOne)"
3. Move Vehicle and Flier to the new Package.
4. Inherit Vehicle and Flier from HiddenOne
5. Implement the method implementMe in Vehicle.

**Now:** Whenever you like to implement from "Flier" you must extends from Vehicle **!**
(because only Vehicle can implement **implementMe**).

This is tricky but works great.

Comment: There also is a more complex solution using protected inner-classes.

Comment: What if someone creates a `Submarine` class within that new package? Then they could implement `HiddenOne` directly, without going through `Vehicle`...

Comment: You can protect your package with security-rules. But ... ok, the protected-inner-class may be easier.