# Is there a way to create Model here without duplicating the code?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I need to use two *similar* libraries one for one specific session of MVC. Means, they (their methods) won't be used simultaneously (I'll use `If...Else` around that specific session to choose methods of only one library at a time). The problem is:

- For both libraries to work, its mandatory for my Entities (Model) to `extend` their classes (wished I was with C++).
- They don't provide any `Interface`. So, I can't do multi-inheritance.

The only choice I have left: Create two different Models each for both libraries & use specific Model based on session (or being used libraries).

But, it'll duplicate the codes in Models. At this time there's no need to sync data between them due to use of persistent storage between MVC sessions. But still, duplicate code is a big headache to manage. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Care to provide some code related to this so we can actually 'see' what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create [Adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for each specific libraray. This would keep your own code clean from the other libraries.

Also you should consider using the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for switching between both libraries. This becomes handy when the code becomes more complex and you can mock the libraries in tests.

Comment: Can you please be more specific.. Maybe, special use of `Adapter Pattern` can be the solution, but I am not getting how I can avoid duplicate models. I am already using Adapters to access models based on specific MVC session.

Comment: In your case, the adapters would extend the classes of the third party library and contain references to your own model objects. The adapters would not duplicate any code from the model. They only act as an interface for library to access your model.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get around including both libraries if that's what you're asking. You could have a few options just depends on how you want things to work.

From what I understand, you could create two classes, each extending a different library, these classes implement an Interface, override any methods you need to.

Pseudo code:

```
private class Lib1Adapter extends Lib1 implements LibAdapter {
   // wrapper methods call lib1 methods
}

private class Lib2Adapter extends Lib2 implements LibAdapter {
   // wrapper methods call lib2 methods
}

public interface LibAdapter {
   // method signatures for publicly accessible methods
}

public class YourModel {
   public LibAdapter la = < boolean statement > ? new Lib1Adapter() : new Lib2Adapter();
}
```

Comment: You should also look at @MarcHauptmann's Answer He has links to what I was trying to describe.

Comment: I don't think one can extend an `interface` from a class... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109173/is-there-a-way-to-guarantee-an-interface-extends-a-class-in-java